# Firebase cloud function sending push notifications with geo location

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I currently have a React-Native app with a firebase real-time database connected. Users may choose to upload data and notify nearby users with a push notification. The users location is saved in the database together with a Firebase token for the push messages.

A cloud function is created that would look for a pushUsed value. If this is true it will gather the tokens and send a message. For now it sends a message to every user, can I rewrite the cloud function to check if a user is near?

This is the part where the tokenArray is created. I was hoping to do something like; 
if user coordinates are within a range of xx miles then add token to the array. Else ignore.

```
const tokenArray = []

  const getDeviceTokensPromise = await admin.database()
  .ref("/UserFCMToken/").once('value', (snapShot) => {

          snapShot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
            tokenArray.push(childSnapshot.val().FCMToken)
          })
        });

        console.log(tokenArray)
      const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenArray, payload);
```

Could anyone help me with this? I am not familiar enough with GPS locations to get this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have gotten the geo location notifications working using geofire-js!

```
        saveLocationHandler = async() => {
        let uid = await AsyncStorage.getItem("ta:auth:userId");
        let userLocationAsync = await AsyncStorage.getItem("ta:auth:userLocation");
        const transformedData = JSON.parse(userLocationAsync);
        const { userLocation } = transformedData;
        const firebaseRef = Firebase.database().ref('Geolocations')
        const geoFire = new GeoFire(firebaseRef)
        const ref = geoFire.ref()
    if (uid || userLocation) {
        geoFire.set(uid, [userLocation.lat, userLocation.lng]); 
        } 
    else {
        console.log('GeoFire UserID en/of userLocation are not known')
        return
    }
}
```

With this function the user location is stored in de Firebase Database using the user ID en GPS location.
In another entry in Firebase I have:

_FCMTokens
__UserID
___FCMToken (for sending push notifications)

I then changed my cloud function to first check which users are near using Geofire.

```
  const tokenArray = []
  const geofireQuery = new GeoFire(admin.database().ref('Geolocations')).query({
    center: [event._data.location[0].lat, event._data.location[0].lng],
    radius: event._data.selectedRange
  })
  .on('key_entered', async (key) => {
    // Geofire only provides an index to query.
    // We'll need to fetch the original object as well
    const getDeviceTokensPromise = await admin.database()
    .ref('/UserFCMToken/'+ key ).once('value', (snapShot) => {

      snapShot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
        tokenArray.push(childSnapshot.val().FCMToken)
                })
          })
    });

      const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenArray, payload);
```

The Geofire query returns every userID that is within the selectedRange (this is an entry that is available in the Firebase Database). On key_entered which is fired with the key fetched the FCMToken for every user. The key is provided by Geofire, which in my case is the userID.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite interesting. I can think of the following:

- Create another function to periodically get all your users' location. This can be done with libraries like [geolocation](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service) or [location](https://github.com/timfpark/react-native-location) for React native. Set your function to update your users' location every 5 or 10 minutes.
- Once you run your original function you get the location of this user and just add the logic to compare if another user is nearby with a query. The query would run on the latest saved location, which should be the most recent one.

The interesting part is that the results of these libraries are returned on *latitude* and *longitude* so you also need to understand [How to calculate distance in miles from longitue and latitude](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/142326/calculating-longitude-length-in-miles).

Hope this is helpful! :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kevin! I currently use expo-location because I started working with that when following a tutorial (The app is now ejected). A quick google search tells me that I can create a background service for expo-location as wel. So that part looks to be covered. 

I would then overwrite the new location in the database. After that writing the code for the distance calculating comes to play. The calculation in your link doesn't make sense yet...have to look into those a little bit further ;-)

Comment: I'm glad to hear that we were on the same channel related to the first part :D Yep, I think you might need that link later since the expo-location [returns](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/docs/pages/versions/unversioned/sdk/location.md#locationgeocodeasyncaddress) _lon_ and _lat_ as part of the results

Comment: Kevin how is your Firebase cloud function knowledge? I'm working with the Geofire package for realizing this functionality however I'm stuck at getting it to work correct.